# How to show that $E(g(X, m, s)) = 0$ for a random variable $X$ iff $m = E(X)$ and $s = var(X)$?

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation, variance, means

> How to show that $E(g(X, m, s)) = 0$ for a random variable $X$ iff $m
>  = E(X)$ and $s = var(X)$?

The broader question and definition of $g$ is this:

[image]

Comment: What is  $E[X-m]$ for an arbitrary $m$? What is $E[(X-m)^2-s]$ for arbitrary $m$ and $s$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a simple substitution,  First line $E(X-m)=\mu-m$.  second line for $m=\mu$, then $E((X-m)^2-s)=\sigma^2-s$